# DNN Site Map not showing all pages

Tags: dotnetnuke

All the pages on the site are set with the default 0.5 priority and the site map settings are even set lower to 0.1 just to be sure this isn't the issue but still only a few pages are generated in the sitemap.

I've tried clearing the app cache and restarting the app pool but still no luck.

https://www.tompkinsinc.com/sitemap.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is cached in the portalid-system folder under sitemap. I’d suggest trying to delete that file first and see if it’s better.